# Restrict variable grouping being used in Azure DevOps Step

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have two variable groups with overlapping keys but different values. I want to use one group under one task [ JSON replace ] and the other group in another [JSON replace ].
I have tried going through the documentations and it says that variables can only be set at root/stage/job levels. Is there a way I can work around it?

Comment: have you tried checking Authorized access to a specific pipeline??

Comment: @SaiSakethGuduru-MT My pipeline has both the tasks so restricting would not help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to use one group under one task [ JSON replace ] and the other group in another [JSON replace ].

According to the document [Specify jobs in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), we could to know that:

> You can organize your pipeline into jobs. Every pipeline has at least
> one job. A job is a series of steps that run sequentially as a unit.
> In other words, **a job is the smallest unit of work that can be
> scheduled to run**.

And the variable group will be added as a preselected condition to the precompiled review stage, we could not re-set in the task level.

To resolve this issue, you could overwrite the specify variable by the [Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md):

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"
```

Comment: Hey Leo , thanks for the answer , in the end I had to split my tasks into jobs and pass the modified files through artifacts between them. I was aware of this method but was looking for a way if we could do this in the multiple steps with each step having it's own set of variables. I hope azure adds step based variables instead of adding everything to env. Thanks for the answer though.!